# Clicking on button which should execute Javascript does not bring result

Tags: selenium-rc, robotframework

I'm having problem, when clicking on button that should execute Javascript, does bring no result.

Here is the part of the logs:

```
20121206 10:02:35.859 :  INFO : Simulating Mouse Over on element 'xpath=//button[contains(@class,"x-btn-text")]/.[contains(text(),"+ Add")]'
20121206 10:02:35.904 :  INFO : Clicking element 'xpath=//button[contains(@class,"x-btn-text")]/.[contains(text(),"+ Add")]'.
20121206 10:02:56.231 :  FAIL : Element 'xpath=//input[@name="type"]' did not appear in 20 seconds
```

Here is the screenshot, how it looks like, when it doesn't work:

[image: +Add button doesn't work]

If I do it manually, clicking the "+ Add" button should execute some Javascript and open this form:

[image: +Add when works]

In this form I want validate Type field (Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=//input[@name="type"]) and so some actions, but that doesn't matter, till I don't get the form open.

I'm using: 
Seleniun server 2.25
Firefox 12.
RFM 2.7.5

What can cause the problem / how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try using keyword `Click Button` instead?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use 'Click Button' instead, but that doesn't solve the problem. Actually, button will be clicked in both ways, but javascript will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Where did you get an expression "`xpath=//button[contains(@class,"x-btn-text")]/.[contains(text(),"+ Add")]`"? Can you add your button an ID and try to click it with xpath pointing at ID identifier, like `xpath//button[@id=addButton]`?

Comment: all buttons have generic IDs, so I can't use them

Comment: by the way the problem is not that the button wouldn't be clicked, but that the clicking doesn't bring any result.